# Next.js 13 server: How should I forward an uploaded file to a 3rd party api?

Tags: post, next.js, file-upload

I've got a Next.js 13 application where the end user can submit a form that includes a file upload. The Next.js server needs to forward this data (including the file(s)) to a 3rd party server. When I call the external server from Swagger, it works OK. When I do the same from Next.js I get a `400` error.

This is my server code (`app/api/contact/route.ts`):

```js
import axios from "axios"
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server"

export async function POST(request: NextRequest) {
  const formData = await request.formData()

  const route = `${process.env.API_URL}/Api/SendContact`

  const response = await axios.post(route, formData, {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
    },
  })

  return NextResponse.json(response.data)
}
```

- I tried without the headers, but I get the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide the code for `formData()`? it could be undefined. This is why you're getting 400 error status.

Comment: When I log `formData` on the server I see the following, so that looks OK:

`FormData {
  [Symbol(state)]: [
    { name: 'file', value: 'C:\\fakepath\\test.png' },
    { name: 'Name', value: 'Tom' },
    { name: 'PhoneNumber', value: '0123456789' },
    { name: 'Message', value: 'Hello there' }
  ]
}`

Comment: The API which you're consuming may have a documentation. Which could contain the required parameters which needs to be passed with in the request

Comment: I know what the required parameters are. I can send a successful request via cURL and also via Swagger. Just when I perform a POST request from Next.js frontend to Next.js backend and from there to the external service, the file gets lost.

Answer (score 0):

400 means bad request, there is a problem with the formatting or data provided in the payload you are sending.

You'll need to review the payload you're sending and the expectation from the API endpoint to make them match, look at the network response and see if the api provides a error message.

As a wild guess check the "Content-Type" value first as most modern API's prefer json over FormData.

If you're stil stuck update your question with the API doc, error message and the formData.

Comment: 1. The external service made the file upload mandatory by mistake. That explained the `400`. 

2. When I send the form without file, it works fine. But strange enough when I add a file, the file isn't sent to the external service when I run `axios.post`. It feels like the `file` object is stripped from the `formData` object.

Answer (score -1):

Below is a simple example of a file upload using axios and form data in Javascript.

```
import axios from "axios";
var fs = require('fs');

let headersList = {
 "Accept": "*/*"
}

let formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append("file", fs.createReadStream("/path-to-file/filename.png"));

let bodyContent =  formdata;

let reqOptions = {
  url: "https://example.com/Api/SendContact",
  method: "POST",
  headers: headersList,
  data: bodyContent,
}

let response = await axios.request(reqOptions);
console.log(response.data);
```

---

As you're working with NextJS API you can parse the incoming request with Formidable package and then use the files attribute.

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import { Formidable } from 'formidable';
import axios from 'axios';

// this is important it disables the default parsing for incoming requests
export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
};

export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) {
  const form = new Formidable();
  const [_fields, files] = await form.parse(req);
  // You'll get multiple files inside files[0]. You can handle accordingly
  if (files?.[0]?.[0]) {
    let headersList = {
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
    };
    let formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append('file', files[0][0].filepath);
    let bodyContent = formdata;
    let reqOptions = {
      url: 'https://example.com/Api/SendContact',
      method: 'POST',
      headers: headersList,
      data: bodyContent,
    };
    let response = await axios.request(reqOptions);
    console.log(response.data);
  } else {
    console.log("No files uploaded")
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Vinod! What would be the path of the file to append if it has just been posted from the frontend as in my example above?

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts! I couldn't get your example working though: got a TypeScript error on `form.parse(req)`. When I googled for that issue I stumbled upon this page: https://codersteps.com/articles/building-a-file-uploader-from-scratch-with-next-js-app-directory

Trying to implement that solution now.